# django, one orm command execute duplicate sql sentence

Tags: mysql, django, orm

test code:

```
1、  b = 1
2、  aa = Forum.objects.values('id')
3、  d = 2
4、  print aa[0]['id']
```

then I monitor the mysql execute with linux command:

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

then I debug the code line by line, 
at line 2 ,the monitor screen print

```
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
```

at line 3 ,the monitor screen print

```
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
```

at line 4 ,the monitor screen print

```
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
25 Query    SELECT `forum`.`id` FROM `forum` ORDER BY `forum`.`display_order` ASC LIMIT 21
```

why one orm sentence execute so many times in the mysql log

Comment: There is no theoretical reason afaik that lines 3 and 4 would trigger a query. Are you sure that you interprete your log file correct? I would recommend you to install `django-toolbar` and examine your queries in there too.

Comment: @Wtower Yes, with diango-toolbar it only execute once. May be there is some bugs in mysql log

Comment: I doubt your logs are wrong, I'd say that your shell is rerunning the query for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querysets are lazy. Queries are evaluated with:

- iteration
- slicing
- pickling / caching
- `repr()`
- `len()`
- `list()`
- `bool()`

Source: [Django documentation: Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Therefore, statements 3 and 4 do not deal with the queryset in any way so it is rather not possible at least in theory to have triggered any query, suggesting there is something off with your log.

[`django-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is a nice app that among other things shows you the executed queries and could help you with that.